# Fourier Transform Good Articles

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to use FT in one of my programming projects, but I need to refresh myself on it. Any good books and articles? The last time I studied it was 12 years ago, when I was in college.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio signal processing ? You will use FFT ? In that case you have to look at the unitary matrix viewpoint for the FFT and look at convolution, filtering, windowing, short time Fourier transform (STFT), AR process, noise. for example : https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/ (I searched "Fourier transform audio signal processing")
and if you are good you can also look at the Wigner–Ville distribution and the general problem of time frequency representations.